# GETDATE()-n when compared to datetime2(7) excludes the matching value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a situation where querying a datetime2(7) field with GETDATE()-n is not returning expected output.

Query with >= GEDATE()-20 returns all dates excluding 4/27 (if run today 5/17)
Query with >= 4/27/2018 returns all dates including 4/27.

Is it something to do with the timepart? even if the timepart is all 0's?

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '04-01-2018',
        @MaxDate DATE = '05-17-2018';

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        DateCol = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate) AS DATETIME2(7))
INTO #temp
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

--SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE DateCol >= GETDATE()-20
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE DateCol >= '2018-04-27'                --excludes the date 4/27

/*
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE DateCol >= GETDATE()-20   --Excludes 4/27
SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE DateCol >= '2018-04-27'   --Expected output includes 4/27
*/
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to '`2018-04-27 00:00:00.0000000`' not greater than `GETDATE()-20`.

`GETDATE()-20` will give something like `'2018-04-27 10:25:37.680'`

For one case you are using only date and for the other scenario it is date and time.

You should change your query like following to change the date-time to date before comparing to get the desired output.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp WHERE DateCol >= cast(GETDATE() -20 as date)
```

Comment: `This is due to '2018-04-27 00:00:00.0000000' not greater than GETDATE()-20`. However, I was using `=` operator as well!!